# ERC 721 - How to determine ownerOf a specific token_id

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, ethereumjs, erc-721

I am having some trouble determining the owner of a specific token_id.

```
const fs = require('fs');

var jsonFile = "abi/ERC721.abi";
var abi = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jsonFile));

const contractAddress = "<ERC721_address>";
const controller = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
const tokenId = web3.utils.keccak256(web3.utils.asciiToHex(<Thing>)); // On-chain contract, computes token_id as keccak(bytes("<Thing>"))
console.log(controller.methods.ownerOf(token_id).call()) // Error: Returned error: execution reverted
```

When I run this code, I keep getting an error. Now, I am quite certain that this is happening because the contract doesn't like the data I am passing to the `ownerOf` function, but I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect your `tokenId`.

Currently, you are using the output of `web3.utils.keccak256` [which is a String](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3).

But the input of ...`ownerOf` is expecting an integer (i.e. a `BN`).

To convert from the former to the latter, please try [`web3.utils.toBN`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#tobn).